# Parsing a dynamically created table

Tags: jquery, parsing

I am trying to parse a dynamically created table and pass the results to a java program to write them to the database. However, the parsing function is returning "jsonRecords: [{"plTime":""}]".

As you will see from the code below I have a table within a table. Initially I am just trying to get the parsing of the main table to work. Next, I will try to parse the sub table for each row (contents dragged from the Activity table on the left and may be empty) and associate each sub table row with the main row above it (i.e., a row may have a number of activities associated with it). If you are able to provide me with assistance on the whole problem then that would be a bonus!

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered centreTable" id="programDetailTable" style="width:100%;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Add</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Activity</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Equip. Needed</th>
            <th>Youth to Bring</th>
            <th>Leaders</th>
            <th>Remove</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <!-- Populate the table with jQuery call -->
    <tbody id="programDetailTablebody">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS
Create table

```
//Add an initial row if there are not currently any program lines
var newRows = "";
    newRows += "<tr><td><button type='button' name='addPDRow'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span></button></td>";
    newRows += "<td><input class='timeWidth' value='07:00'></input></td>";
    //Activity table
    newRows += "<td>";
    newRows +=      "<table>";
    newRows +=      "<tbody id='activity2Tablebody'>";
    newRows +=          "<tr><td>";
    newRows +=              "<input></input>";
    newRows +=              "<div class='droppableItem'></div>";
    newRows +=          "</td></tr>";
    newRows +=      "</tbody>";
    newRows +=      "</table>";
    newRows +="</td>";

    newRows += "<td><input class='activityWidth'></input></td>";
    newRows += "<td><input></input></td>";
    newRows += "<td><input></input></td>";
    newRows += "<td><input></input></td>";
    newRows += "<td><button type='button' name='removePDRow'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus'></button></td></tr>";

$('#programDetailTablebody').append(newRows);
```

Parse table

```
function getProgramLines() {
    var records  = [];
    var keyNames = ['plTime', 'plActivity', 'plLocation', 'plEquipNeeded', 'plYouthToBring', 'plLeaders'];

    $("#programDetailTable tbody tr").each(function(i) {

        var record = {};
        $('td', this).each(function(j) {
            if (keyNames[j]){
                if (j === 0 || j > 6){
                //Ignore the buttons in the first and last columns
            }else{
                var text = $.trim($(this).text()); // GET TRIMMED TEXT
                record[keyNames[j]] = text;
            }
        });
        records.push(record);
    });

    return records;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I have been beavering away at this and found that "programDetailTablebody" should be "programDetailTable". However, this still does not return a result, just blanks for each field. I have update the question accordingly.

Comment: I think I have narrowed it down to the line "var text = $.trim($(this).text()); // GET TRIMMED TEXT". I have tried "var text = $.trim($(this).find(".keyvalue input").val());"; however, both return blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
var text = $.trim($(this).text());
```

With:

```
var text = $.trim($(this).find(".pdValue").val());
```

And add to each input:

```
class='pdValue'
```